# How to write the data to USB stick(Pendrive) from the application in android

Tags: android, file-writing, usb-drive

In my application i have to write the Data to USB stick(Pendrive) from the application.

My application will support to write the data to Local memory and USB stick(Pendrive).

Currently i am able to write the data to Local memory ,but i am unable to write to USB stick(Pendrive).

**Do we need to add any extra permission other than WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?**

**Is writing to USB stick(Pendrive) through app possible?**

I am able to ready the files which are there in the USB,i am not able to write the data.

Here is the folder path  where i want to write the data.
"**/storage/usb1/TestFolder**"

Can i get some help on this?

Comment: how do you put USB stick to your phone?

Comment: "Do we need to add any extra permission other than WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?" -- no, but bear in mind that [the Android SDK did not support removable storage prior to Android 4.4](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). And on Android 4.4+, you cannot write to arbitrary locations on removable storage -- you are limited to methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Comment: Thank you for reply..We ordered have some XXX company device where the Device will have USB port where user can connect the USB.
From the application i should write some data to USB.
The device is 4.4.4 version.

Comment: So is it concluded that we cannot write any data to Pendrive programmatically in android?.Can some one confirm on this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write some data to USB, we need

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"
```

By referring some links i got to know that the above permission can get by Provider of the device.

So we can apply above mechanism to get it done.